# pyspark not able to start

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, startup

I am having Windows 8.1 operating system. I installed *apache spark* and then, installed *Java JDK*. I am using *git bash* in *windows*. I am having below setting in my `.bash_profile` of *git bash*.

```
export SPARK_HOME="/c/tools/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7" 
export PATH="$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH"  
export JAVA_HOME="/c/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/"
```

When I try to call *pyspark*, I am getting error as given below.

> /c/tools/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/pyspark: line 45: python:
>   command not found Error: Could not find or load main class
>   org.apache.spark.launcher.Main

I tried running *spark-shell* in the path "/c/tools/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/". Still getting the same error.

Please help me in making pyspark running in my machine.

Comment: Please check if you have set python path. follow [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31665402/how-to-start-a-spark-shell-using-pyspark-in-windows

Comment: It did not work out for me. I have added answer, which finally worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to make pyspark work in Windows, by following the steps in the blog

http://nishutayaltech.blogspot.com/2015/04/how-to-run-apache-spark-on-windows7-in.html

I had to install few more tools and set environment variables and finally make it working.